# How do I make lock screen ask for a password on my USB Ubuntu install?

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, portable, screensaver

Whenever I lock the screen on my USB Ubuntu install be it manually or automatically when I get back it just shows the desktop again without asking for a password.

How can I enable the password lock again?  This way it's quite useless.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: do you have automatic login enabled (not on the screensaver/lock, i mean when the system first boots up)?

Comment: This might help: http://superuser.com/questions/111954/xubuntu-9-10-running-on-virtualbox-never-goes-idle

Comment: @Quack: I have disabled the autologin, and have a password set on my own account

@Richard: Will take a look

Comment: Just checked, have gnome-screensaver running, and I don't want to switch as it should work just fine, trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: i wrote up [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/119254/how-to-switch-users-without-entering-password/119813#119813) for a guy looking for passwordless logins on ubuntu.  if i were you i'd check PAM settings for sanity.  same guy asked another question in which i did some [digging around on how the screensaver lock works](http://superuser.com/questions/120747/how-to-wake-from-screensaver-directly-to-the-login-screen-in-ubuntu/125658#125658) -- that stuff about DBus didn't end up helping him but maybe it'll point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is just a bug in the usb version of ubuntu, finally have a laptop so no need for ubuntu usb installs.